# mySQL return not empty field

Tags: mysql

I have two fields, but I want to return only the non-empty one.

```
select firstname, lastname, (if firstname != empty, then firstname else lastname) as name from users;
```

How do I go about doing something like above. Am not sure what should be inside the round brackets. I don't want to use PHP post-processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for both `null` values as well as empty strings (`''`)

```
SELECT IF(LENGTH(firstname), firstname, lastname) as name from users;
```

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways you can do this in MySQL.

You can use the [coalesce()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function which returns the first non-null value among its arguments.

```
select coalesce(firstname, lastname) as name from users;
```

Alternatively, you could use a [case statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case):

```
select case when firstname is not null then firstname else lastname end as name from users;
```

Or you could use the [if()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function:

```
select if(firstname is not null, firstname, lastname) as name from users;
```

Or you could use the [ifnull()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function:

```
select ifnull(firstname, lastname) as name from users;
```

Comment: @Alec Smart: That's ok. The important thing is that you got a correct answer to your question.